# user-defined kernels on multiple gpu in cupy

Tags: multi-gpu, cupy

I'm trying to launch raw kernels in cupy on multiple gpu.

Example 1 (RawKernel):

```py
import numpy as np
import cupy

gpu_indices = (0,1)
n_gpu = len(gpu_indices)

source = """
extern "C" {
    __global__
    void my_add(const float *x1, const float *x2, float *y, const int n)
    {
        const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
        if (tid < n) {
            y[tid] = x1[tid] + x2[tid];
        }
    }
}
"""

add_kernel = [None] * n_gpu
for gpu_id in gpu_indices:
    with cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id):
        add_kernel[gpu_id] = cupy.RawKernel(source, 'my_add')

x1 = [None] * n_gpu
x2 = [None] * n_gpu
y = [None] * n_gpu
streams = [None] * n_gpu

for gpu_id in gpu_indices:
    with cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id):
        x1[gpu_id] = cupy.arange(25, dtype=cupy.float32).reshape(5, 5)
        x2[gpu_id] = cupy.arange(25, dtype=cupy.float32).reshape(5, 5)
        y[gpu_id] = cupy.zeros((5, 5), dtype=cupy.float32)
        streams[gpu_id] = cupy.cuda.stream.Stream()

for gpu_id in gpu_indices:
    cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id).use()
    streams[gpu_id].use()
    add_kernel[gpu_id]((5,), (5,), (x1[gpu_id], x2[gpu_id], y[gpu_id], x1[gpu_id].size), stream=streams[gpu_id])
    streams[gpu_id].synchronize()
    print(y[gpu_id])
```

This code runs without error with `gpu_id=(0,)` (single gpu) and `gpu_id=(0,1)` (dual gpu) on my machine.

Example 2 (RawModule):

```py
import numpy as np
import cupy

gpu_indices = (0,1)
n_gpu = len(gpu_indices)

source = """
extern "C" {
    __global__
    void my_add(const float *x1, const float *x2, float *y, const int n)
    {
        const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
        if (tid < n) {
            y[tid] = x1[tid] + x2[tid];
        }
    }
}
"""

module = cupy.RawModule(code=source)

add_kernel = [None] * n_gpu
for gpu_id in gpu_indices:
    with cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id):
        add_kernel[gpu_id] = module.get_function('my_add')

# same as example 1

x1 = [None] * n_gpu
x2 = [None] * n_gpu
y = [None] * n_gpu
streams = [None] * n_gpu

for gpu_id in gpu_indices:
    with cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id):
        x1[gpu_id] = cupy.arange(25, dtype=cupy.float32).reshape(5, 5)
        x2[gpu_id] = cupy.arange(25, dtype=cupy.float32).reshape(5, 5)
        y[gpu_id] = cupy.zeros((5, 5), dtype=cupy.float32)
        streams[gpu_id] = cupy.cuda.stream.Stream()

for gpu_id in gpu_indices:
    cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id).use()
    streams[gpu_id].use()
    add_kernel[gpu_id]((5,), (5,), (x1[gpu_id], x2[gpu_id], y[gpu_id], x1[gpu_id].size), stream=streams[gpu_id])
    streams[gpu_id].synchronize()
    print(y[gpu_id])
```

Only difference between two codes is the way of getting kernel. In Example 2, cupy.RawModule() is called to compile `source` and kernels are acquired by using get_function(). However, this code fails with `gpu_id=(0,1)`:

```
[[ 0.  2.  4.  6.  8.]
 [10. 12. 14. 16. 18.]
 [20. 22. 24. 26. 28.]
 [30. 32. 34. 36. 38.]
 [40. 42. 44. 46. 48.]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_rawmodule.py", line 42, in <module>
    add_kernel[gpu_id]((5,), (5,), (x1[gpu_id], x2[gpu_id], y[gpu_id], x1[gpu_id].size), stream=streams[gpu_id])
  File "cupy/core/raw.pyx", line 66, in cupy.core.raw.RawKernel.__call__
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 162, in cupy.cuda.function.Function.__call__
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 144, in cupy.cuda.function._launch
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 293, in cupy.cuda.driver.launchKernel
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 118, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE: invalid resource handle
```

Could anyone provide an example of cupy.RawModule on multiple gpu? To me RawModule is preferred over RawKernel for some reasons.

Here is my environment:

- cupy 7.3, numpy 1.18.1
- cuda 10.2 (10.2.89_440.33.01)
- python 3.6.10 (anaconda)
- Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa (based on Ubuntu 18.04)
- Two gtx 1080 Ti gpu (works well with native CUDA C/C++ programming)

add: If I try to compile `source` on each gpu like:

```
module = [None] * n_gpu
add_kernel = [None] * n_gpu
for gpu_id in gpu_indices:
    with cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id):
        module[gpu_id] = cupy.RawModule(code=source)
        add_kernel[gpu_id] = module[gpu_id].get_function('my_add')
```

Then I have following error messages:

```
module[gpu_id] = cupy.RawModule(code=source)
  File "cupy/core/raw.pyx", line 252, in cupy.core.raw.RawModule.__init__
  File "cupy/core/carray.pxi", line 146, in cupy.core.core.compile_with_cache
  File "cupy/core/carray.pxi", line 194, in cupy.core.core.compile_with_cache
  File "/home/kejang/anaconda3/envs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/cuda/compiler.py", line 287, in compile_with_cache
    extra_source, backend)
  File "/home/kejang/anaconda3/envs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/cuda/compiler.py", line 335, in _compile_with_cache_cuda
    mod.load(cubin)
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 197, in cupy.cuda.function.Module.load
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 199, in cupy.cuda.function.Module.load
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 240, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleLoadData
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 118, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_CONTEXT_IS_DESTROYED: context is destroyed
```

This is strange because I think `source` should be compiled on each gpu like Example 1.